# How to save a contact with multiple phone numbers on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to save from code a contact with multiple phone numbers.

I see this is sort of possible using the StoredContact class. However, there are only predefined contact properties that I can use to save a phone number (e.g. KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, KnownContactProperties.Telephone, etc.). I don't see a way to save an arbitrarily long list of phone numbers using this class. Nor do I see a way of setting a custom property name (custom properties are in fact supported, it's just that they are ignored by the People app, making them useless in my case).

The Contact class in the Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts namespace on the other hand does seem to support a list of phone numbers. From the looks of it though, the classes in this namespace are restricted to read only access on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

The [StoredContact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.personalinformation.storedcontact) class does not support the scenario for storing multiple phone numbers.

Although the updated [KnownContactProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.personalinformation.knowncontactproperties) class has properties AlternateMobileTelephone,AlternateTelephone,AlternateWorkTelephone to add extra numbers for the contact.

So you can store extra numbers in these properties.